# Typescript generic type default when not being used

Tags: typescript, generics

I have an interface similar to this:

```
interface ISomething<TMulti extends object> {
    value: number | string;
    text: string | TMulti;
}
```

The text part could either be a simple string or an object map implementing some specific interface. In majority of cases it's going to be just a simple non-nullable string, so I would like to set the `TMulti` generic type default to something to east the use of this interface. My choices are

- `{}`
- `null`
- `never`

The best option seems to be `never` but I've never seen it used as a generic type default and am not exactly sure what a type of `string | never` actually means? Is it identical to `string`? Both of the other two options, allow me to set the value of `text` to some undesired value.

**The question is: can type `never` be used as a generic type default and what does it mean is such case?**

> ***Additional note***: I'm using Typescript in strict mode, so `string` can't be null per compiler requirements, which is also what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use `never` as a default:

```
interface ISomething<TMulti extends object = never> {
    value: number | string;
    text: string | TMulti;
}

const a: ISomething = {
    value: 'str',
    text: 'str'
}

const b: ISomething<{ example: string }> = {
    value: 2,
    text: {
        example: 'str'
    }
}
```

The examples above show that where you don't specify the type, it knows `text` should be a string. So `never` is a good choice, for which you should be congratulated as I feel fraudulent simply confirming your correct suggestion.

Comment: Might be useful, the PR introducing never: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/8652. You can find there that: Because never is a subtype of every type, it is always omitted from union types and it is ignored in function return type inference as long as there are other types being returned.

Comment: So what would happen to a property in the `ISomething<TMulti extends object = never>` that would have a property `manNotBe: TMulti`. Does that mean taht when `TMulti` is `never` that the property doesn't exist?